# Can Use other repositories yml file to other pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-repos, azure-devops-pipelines

Repo 1 and Branch Name: Repo1Branch

```yaml
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
```

I want to call Repo 1 form Repo 2 pipeline

Repo 2 and Branch Name: Repo2Branch

```yaml
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: PROJECTNAME/Repo 1
      ref: Repo1Branch 
  
steps:
 - template: azure-pipelines.yml@Repo 1
```

Comment: Hi, If the answer resolved your question, you could [Accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) as an Answer , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can it is mentioned here - [Use other repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#use-other-repositories)

In one repo you define template

```
# Repo: Contoso/BuildTemplates
# File: common.yml
parameters:
- name: 'vmImage'
  default: 'ubuntu 16.04'
  type: string

jobs:
- job: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: ${{ parameters.vmImage }}
  steps:
  - script: npm install
  - script: npm test
```

and then you reference it

```yaml
# Repo: Contoso/LinuxProduct
# File: azure-pipelines.yml
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: github
      name: Contoso/BuildTemplates

jobs:
- template: common.yml@templates  # Template reference
```

but this has to be template. Not full pipeline. You cannot reference full pipeline as a template as you did above. So for instance `trigger` and `pool` are not allowed keywords in a template.

Comment: Yes, I was using trigger and pool now it's working Thank you.

Comment: @Prashantshivhare cool. Can you consider marking my reply as answer? It will let other user focus on not solved issues.

Comment: Yes Sure Thank you once again @Krzysztof Madej